# Как провести преобразование входящего массива объектов в объект и при этом поменять местами ключи со значениями?

Tags: javascript, массивы, объекты

Задача:
Напишите функцию которая преобразует входящий массив объектов в в объект. Ключами (key) возвращаемого объекта должны быть значения элементов исходного массива, значениями возвращаемого - ключи исходного.

Examples:

```
input: [ { k1:v1 }, { k2:v2 }, { k3:v3 } ]

output: { v1:k1, v2:k2, v3:k3, }
```

Пробовал так, только на выходе массив

```
function arrayToObject (array) { 
    array.reduce(function (result, item, index) { 
        var key = Object.keys(item)[0]; 
        var value = item[key]; 
        var obj = {}; 
        obj[value] = key; 
        result.push(obj); 
        return result; 
    }, []); 
}
```

Comment: сами пробовали?

Comment: Пробовал так, только на выходе массив: 
function arrayToObject (array)
{
  array.reduce(function (result, item, index)
  {
    var key = Object.keys(item)[0];
    var value = item[key];
    var obj = {};
    obj[value] = key;
    result.push(obj);

    return result;
  }, []);
}

Answer (score 1):

Проблема приведенного кода в том, что во-первых, функция ничего не возвращает, во-вторых, начальным значением был выбран массив. Поэтому странно ожидать на выходе объект.

После исправления указанных ошибок можно перейти к алгоритму свертки.

По сути внутри одного reduce должен располагаться второй, который бы добавлял значения из текущего объекта в результирующий.

Для этого можно использовать как метод [`.keys`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) возвращающий массив ключей, который затем можно свернуть в объект, указав начальное значение в `result`, так и метод [`.entries`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries) который также возвращает массив, элементами которого является пара ключ-значение.

Конечный код может выглядеть так:

```js
var t = [{
  k1: 'v1'
}, {
  k2: 'v2'
}, {
  k3: 'v3'
}];

function arrayToObject(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(result, item) {
    return Object.keys(item).reduce((r, key) => {
      result[item[key]] = key;
      return result;
    }, result);
  }, {});
}

console.log(arrayToObject(t));
```

Или так:

```js
var t = [{
  k1: 'v1'
}, {
  k2: 'v2'
}, {
  k3: 'v3'
}];

function arrayToObject(array) {
  return array.reduce(function(result, item) {
    return Object.entries(item).reduce((r, [key, value]) => Object.assign(result, {
      [value]: key
    }), result);
  }, {});
}

console.log(arrayToObject(t));
```

Answer (score 0):

Можно так:

```js
function revert(input) {
  return input.reduce((s, c) => {
    Object.entries(c).map(function(item) {
      let [value, key] = item;
      s[key] = value;
    });
    return s;
  }, {})
};

let test = [ { k1: "v1" }, { k2: "v2" }, { k3: "v3" } ];
console.log(revert(test));
```

Comment: Спасибо огромное за помощь, в итоге твои вариант и взял на вооружение.))

Answer (score -1):

```js
const arr = [{ k1: 'v1' }, { k2: 'v2' }, { k3: 'v3' }]; 
const result = Object.fromEntries(arr.map(obj => Object.entries(obj)[0].reverse())); 
console.log(JSON.stringify(result));
```

### *Ред. 2020 года*

Как и ожидалось, метод `fromEntries` был включен в стандарт EcmaScript, и теперь [прекрасно поддерживается эвергрин браузерами](https://caniuse.com/mdn-javascript_builtins_object_fromentries).
<sub>*Спасибо тем, кто в 2019г. минусовал этот **первый ответ на ruSO** о данном методе - за их адекватность, поддержку, и вообще веру в развитие! Благодаря вам, данное сообщество стало тем, чем оно является...*</sub>

Старый ответ:

> Метод `Object.fromEntries()` уже поддерживается актуальными версиями Chrome и Firefox (включая мобильные).
>  Он станет стандартным в этом году - при выходе ES10.
>  
>
>  [Полифилл](https://github.com/es-shims/Object.fromEntries)
>  <sub>+ [понифилл](https://github.com/feross/fromentries) (без поддержки IE и пр.)</sub>

Comment: в каких именно браузерах поддерживается эта функция?